# How can I get all keys from a JSON column in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

If I have a table with a column named `json_stuff`, and I have two rows with

`{ "things": "stuff" }` and `{ "more_things": "more_stuff" }`

in their `json_stuff` column, what query can I make across the table to receive `[ things, more_things ]` as a result?

How can I get all keys from a JSON column in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Use this:

```
select jsonb_object_keys(json_stuff) from table;
```

(Or just `json_object_keys` if you're using just JSON.)

The PostgreSQL JSON documentation is quite good. [Take a look](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html).

And as it is stated in the documentation, the function only gets the outer most keys. So if the data is a nested JSON structure, the function will not return any of the deeper keys.

Comment: This query give you all keys, but if you really need get all possibles keys without repetition this is the query `select jsonb_object_keys(json_stuff) as key from table group by key;`

Comment: @Cyberguille There's DISTINCT too, which is meant for that.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is significant slower than `group by`. Don't know why.

Comment: I'd urge readers to be cautious of statements like "DISTINCT is significant slower than group by" unless there is reproducable evidence of why, and on what version(s), and under what circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

```
WITH t(json_stuff) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"things": "stuff"}'::JSON),
  ('{"more_things": "more_stuff"}'::JSON)
)
SELECT array_agg(stuff.key) result 
FROM t, json_each(t.json_stuff) stuff;
```

Comment: array_agg(distinct(stuff.key)) will put the distinct key into an single array.

Comment: Next time explain what you're supposed to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example if you want to get the key list of each object:

```
select array_agg(json_keys),id from (
select json_object_keys(json_stuff) as json_keys,id from table) a group by a.id
```

Here `id` is the identifier or unique value of each row. If the row cannot be distinguished by identifier, maybe it's better to try `PL/pgSQL`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that implements the same semantics as MySQL's `JSON_KEYS()`, which...:

- is `NULL` safe (i.e. when the array is empty, it produces `[]`, not `NULL`, or an empty result set)
- produces a JSON array, which is what I would have expected from how the question was phrased.

```sql
SELECT
  o,
  (
    SELECT coalesce(json_agg(j), json_build_array())
    FROM json_object_keys(o) AS j (j)
  )
FROM (
  VALUES ('{}'::json), ('{"a":1}'::json), ('{"a":1,"b":2}'::json)
) AS t (o)
```

Replace `json` by `jsonb` if needed.

Producing:

```
|o            |coalesce  |
|-------------|----------|
|{}           |[]        |
|{"a":1}      |["a"]     |
|{"a":1,"b":2}|["a", "b"]|
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert `json_column` and `table`

```
select distinct(tableProps.props) from (
select jsonb_object_keys(<json_column>) as props from <table>
) as tableProps
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get the amount of keys from a JSONB structure, so I'm doing something like this:

```
select into cur some_jsonb from mytable where foo = 'bar';
select into keys array_length(array_agg(k), 1) from jsonb_object_keys(cur) as k;
```

I feel it is a little bit wrong, but it works. It's unfortunate that we can't get an array directly from the `json_object_keys()` function. That would save us some code.